# Get multiple instances of a class to log to a file using Python logging with Bottle

Tags: python, logging, scope, bottle, python-module

I have a bottle web app that I am trying to get to log to a file.

Each page visit instantiates a new class so I am trying to link the logger of each class to the module logger so that they all log to the same file.

Two questions:

A) Will this cause file writing conflicts if multiple instances of the class are logging at the same time?  I think no because they go through the module level logger.  Did I create this correctly?

B) Nothing is showing up in my logfile.log file.  I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
from bottle import route, run
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('server')
fh = logging.FileHandler('./log/logfile.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(fh)

class userclass:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('server.userclass')
        self.name = name
        try:
            raise Exception("Uh oh!")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("There's a problem.")
            return

@route('/<name>')
def user(name):
    newuser = userclass(name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Python is probably being lazy about the log file and not flushing it. Try gracefully shutting down the process and _then_ checking the log file

Comment: Tried stopping the process and then checking the file... still nothing there.

Comment: I tried on my system and it works as expected: the log contains one "There's a problem." for each matching request. I copied and pasted the code from the question, then created a `log` subdirectory, then ran the script. (Python 2.7, Ubuntu). I had to change the port used to 8000, but I made no other changes.

Comment: Okay, that's good.  I am on Windows 7 with Python 2.7.  It is creating the file but when I open it in Notepad, there's nothing in it.

Comment: Just cloned it to a Linux AWS instance and you're right... worked perfectly.  Any idea what the issue on windows is?

Comment: I just tried on Windows 7 with Python 2.6 - no problems there, either. Try on a different Windows machine, if you can.

Comment: Ok I will.  It will ultimately be running on Linux so not a huge problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('server')
fh = logging.FileHandler('./log/logfile.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

with:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='./log/logfile.log')
```

You need to initiate the logger first with the `logging.basicConfig()` function. This will create a basic configuration in the root logger, all other loggers obtained through `logging.getLogger()` will use this base - you can always add handlers to those new logs, change their formats, or even their level - But you need to first call the basic configuration on the root logger.

Comment: A call to `basicConfig` shouldn't be *required* - the OP's code looks OK, except that no level is being set on the logger (so it will default to `WARNING`, but that should catch `ERROR` events too.)

Comment: Thanks.  Just to confirm, it's set the baseConfig and then call getLogger in that order?  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='./log/logfile.log')
logger = logging.getLogger('server')

Comment: The problem is not the code. You have some other problem - are you sure the user you are using has the ability to write to files? is the directory reachable? Try using a variable for the file name, and also printing its location, you never know what you might learn. Regardless - the above code I supplied is the correct way to initiate a root logger.